# Поиск файлов в каталогах

Tags: java

Задача: найти файлы в каталоге и подкаталогах, и сохранить в папку result.

В чём проблема: всего файлов 86000, а id, по которым нужно искать 3500(у меня массив их). Не могу найти оптимизированный код, чтобы смог быстро выполнить задачу(писал на VBS скрипт, но там неделю буду решать эту задачу).

У меня есть папка, в ней ещё 12 папок, в каждой из папок примерно по несколько тысяч файлов.

Можете показать какой-нибудь рабочий код для поиска и сохранения схожих файлов в отдельную папку? Буду благодарен.

Comment: а что такое ID? это имена файлов или как?

Comment: Да, это имена файлов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вместо массива ID используйте `Set<>`. Это позволит ускорить проверку на существование ID
2. Если этого будет недостаточно, то распаралельте задачу. Создайте пул из нескольких потоков (но не больше, чем ядер процессора) и пусть каждый поток ищет файлы в одной папке

Количество ядер в системе можно узнать, вызвав функцию

```
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

Comment: =) Писать код под конкретный процессор штоле? У кого то их 2, а у кого-то 8 ядер с 16ю потоками.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Почему? `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();`

Comment: ага, теперь понял.